# cant get firefox to work with protractor and selenium standalone

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am trying to use firefox 59.0 with protractor 5.3.1 for the first time. Im unclear on the setup, but ive done.

```
npm install --save-dev selenium-server-standalone-jar
selenium-standalone install
```

But do i have to run `webdriver-manager start` from a different tab in terminal?

My test will run in Chrome, but fails in firefox. I have also tried with both `directConnect true` and `directConnect false.`

```
WebDriverError: Unable to parse new session response: {"value":{"error":"session not created","message":"Failed to start browser /usr/local/bin/firefox-bin: permission denied","stacktrace":""}}
```

exports.config = {

```
  seleniumAddress: 'localhost:4444',

  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  getPageTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts' // will run all e2e tests in the project          
  ],

  multiCapabilities: [{
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    directConnect: true,
  }, {
    'browserName': 'firefox',
    directConnect: true,
  }],
  marionette: true,

  shardTestFiles: true, 
  maxInstances: 3,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you use `webdriver-manager` to manage selenium-server.jar and webdriver binaries if you use `protractor`.

**First**, execute `npm init` to init a `package.json`file.

**Second**, execute `npm install -S protractor` to install and add `protractor` as your project dependency.

**Third**, execute `node_modules\.bin\webdriver-manager update` to install selenium-server-standalone.jar and chrome & firefox webdriver binaries to project's `node_modules` folder.

**Forth**, If you use `directConnect: true`,  you no need to execute `node_modules\.bin\webdriver-manager start` to start a selenium server on local before run test script.

Otherwise if you set `seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'`, you need to do that before execute test script.  Only one running selenium server is enough, no need to start it every time before running test script.

**Note** , all above commands need to be executed under project folder where the `package.json` resides.